# scaling the sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: softmax, cross-entropy

How could I scale gradients where the loss comes from **sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits**. For example, I was trying to divide by 128 as below, but I found error:

```
new_gradients = [(grad/128, var) for (grad, var) in gradients] 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'IndexedSlices' and 'int'
```

The code I was using is below:

```
loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels)

gradients = opt.compute_gradient(loss)

new_gradients = [(grad/128, var) for (grad, var) in gradients]

train_step = opt.appy_gradients(new_gradients)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve the problem as follows:

```
new_gradients = [(grad/128, var) for (grad, var) in gradients]
```

should be

```
new_gradients = [(tf.div(grad, 128), var) for (grad, var) in gradients]
```